# Comultiplication in a tensor algebra.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let $V$ be a vector space. Then we have the tensor algebra $TV = \oplus_{i=0}^{\infty} T^i V$. In [the webpage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_algebra), it is said that the comultiplication $\Delta: TV \to TV \otimes TV$ is given by the following formulas:
\begin{align}
& \Delta(x) = x \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes x, \ x \in V \\
& \Delta(x_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes x_m) = \Delta(x_1) \cdots \Delta(x_m), \ x_i \in V.
\end{align}
I am trying to compute $\Delta(x_1 \otimes x_2)$ and $\Delta(x_1 \otimes x_2 \otimes x_3)$ explicitly.

Let $x_1, x_2, x_3 \in V$. Then
\begin{align}
& \Delta(x_1 \otimes x_2) \\
& = \Delta(x_1) \Delta(x_2) \\
& = (1 \otimes x_1 + x_1 \otimes 1)(1 \otimes x_2 + x_2 \otimes 1) \\
& = 1 \otimes 1 \otimes x_1 \otimes x_2 + 1 \otimes x_2 \otimes x_1 \otimes 1 + x_1 \otimes 1 \otimes 1 \otimes x_2 + x_1 \otimes x_2 \otimes 1 \otimes 1.
\end{align}
Is this correct? What is the value of $\Delta(x_1 \otimes x_2 \otimes x_3)$? Thank you very much.

Comment: $(1\otimes x_1)(1\otimes x_2)=1\otimes (x_1x_2)$, the multiplication of tensors is defined pointwise. Also, theorem 3.2.4 of Quantum groups by Kassel shows the general formula.